# Should user management be done through IdentityServer or just Authentication in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, identityserver4

I have a setup with 3 web applications:

1. Web API
2. MVC app
3. Identity Server for Auth

Currently the user is sent over to Identity Server to login and then sent back to the MVC app. Then the MVC app makes calls to the Web API.

If I were to setup a User management section (i.e. User listing with basic CRUD) Should this be part of the IdentityServer app or MVC app? I would assume the best way to do this would be to create a UserController in the Web API that uses the built in User Manager. Then from the MVC app make calls to this API to display the UI.

Comment: Why do you have 3? Webapi, MVC App and Identity Server?   User logs in to Identity Server, Token is returned to the client,  Client Appends token when Calling Web Api,  Web-api uses token a validates back against identity server,  Web api can optionally map the subject Id to custom users table.

Comment: basically to answer your question only identity server need user manager, the OIDC client handles the rest, once you put on authorization attributes

Comment: Too broad and primary opinion based

Comment: @johnny5 not sure what you are saying can you elaborate. I have 3 separate projects because I want the Web API to be separate from the MVC app for several reasons.

Comment: Okay, despite the amount of projects the concept should still be the same.  Have your user's and permissions table on IDSV4,  Request the claims you need from the during the login and either store them in another table or cache them or hold them on the client, and just link the user using its subjectId

Comment: @johnny5 I understand that all of that stuff should be handled on IDSV4 but I was wondering where basic User crud functions would go. Wouldn't it make sense for the Web API to manage this stuff since their will be UI for it?

Comment: Idsv4 already handles the crud action,  but if you want to update something like first name, it should happen on idsv4, if you want you can store additional profile data on your webapi to avoid syncing your updates.